# How can I replace a RNN with a Transformer model while ensuring the same outputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, reinforcement-learning

I have a RNN that returns actions and hidden states for an agent in a Reinforcement Learning environment. I am trying to replace the code with a transformer while trying to keep the code functionality and outputs same. However, transformers do not output hidden states. So I try to use a dummy hidden state. But that obviously throws an error.

Here is the RNN code

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class RNNAgent(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, args):
        super(RNNAgent, self).__init__()
        self.args = args

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_shape, args.rnn_hidden_dim)
        self.rnn = nn.GRUCell(args.rnn_hidden_dim, args.rnn_hidden_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(args.rnn_hidden_dim, args.n_actions)

    def init_hidden(self):
        # make hidden states on same device as model
        return self.fc1.weight.new(1, self.args.rnn_hidden_dim).zero_()

    def forward(self, inputs, hidden_state):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(inputs))
        h_in = hidden_state.reshape(-1, self.args.rnn_hidden_dim)
        h = self.rnn(x, h_in)
        q = self.fc2(h)
        return q, h
```

Here is the code I wrote to replace this RNN with a Decision Transformer

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch

class DTagent(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, args):
        super(DTagent, self).__init__()

        self.args = args
        self.n_actions = args.n_actions
        self.n_agents = args.n_agents
        self.state_shape = input_shape
        self.output_type = "p"

        self.dt = MultiAgentDecisionTransformer(input_shape, args)

    def forward(self, inputs, h):
        # In this version, we're ignoring h because Decision Transformer doesn't maintain one
        # But to keep the interface consistent, we keep it as an argument

        q = self.dt(inputs, inputs)  # Double `inputs` as the DT expects state and action, but here we just need the state representation
        
        # Since the Decision Transformer doesn't use a hidden state like the RNN, 
        # we return a dummy tensor filled with zeros that matches the expected shape.
        h = torch.zeros_like(inputs)

        return q, h  # We're returning dummy_h as the new "hidden_state" because Decision Transformer doesn't use one

    def init_hidden(self):
        # This method returns a placeholder hidden state for the first time step, which will be ignored by the forward method
        return None

class MultiAgentDecisionTransformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, args):
        super(MultiAgentDecisionTransformer, self).__init__()

        self.state_shape = input_shape
        self.n_actions = args.n_actions
        self.n_agents = args.n_agents
        self.embed_dim = args.rnn_hidden_dim
        self.num_heads = 5
        self.num_layers = 2

        self.state_embed = nn.Linear(self.state_shape[0], self.embed_dim)
        self.action_embed = nn.Embedding(self.n_actions, self.embed_dim)

        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=self.embed_dim,
            nhead=self.num_heads,
            num_encoder_layers=self.num_layers,
            num_decoder_layers=self.num_layers
        )

        self.action_decoder = nn.Linear(self.embed_dim, self.n_actions)

    def forward(self, state, action):
        state_emb = self.state_embed(state)
        action_emb = self.action_embed(action)

        # Handling multiple agents' embeddings, here we are averaging them
        action_emb = torch.mean(action_emb, dim=2)  # [batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim]

        # Concatenate embeddings
        x = state_emb + action_emb

        # Transformer forward pass
        transformer_out = self.transformer(x, x)

        # Decode the transformer output to action space
        action_logits = self.action_decoder(transformer_out)

        return action_logits
```

But I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent calls WITHOUT Sacred internals):
  File "src/main.py", line 35, in my_main
    run(_run, config, _log)
  File "/homelocal/3rd Year/DT_RL/SeCA/src/run.py", line 49, in run
    run_sequential(args=args, logger=logger)
  File "/homelocal/3rd Year/DT_RL/SeCA/src/run.py", line 109, in run_sequential
    mac = mac_REGISTRY[args.mac](buffer.scheme, groups, args)
  File "/homelocal/3rd Year/DT_RL/SeCA/src/controllers/basic_controller.py", line 12, in __init__
    self._build_agents(input_shape)
  File "/homelocal/3rd Year/DT_RL/SeCA/src/controllers/basic_controller.py", line 65, in _build_agents
    self.agent = agent_REGISTRY[self.args.agent](input_shape, self.args)
  File "/homelocal/3rd Year/DT_RL/SeCA/src/modules/agents/rnn_agent.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.dt = MultiAgentDecisionTransformer(input_shape, args)
  File "/homelocal/3rd Year/DT_RL/SeCA/src/modules/agents/rnn_agent.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.state_embed = nn.Linear(self.state_shape[0], self.embed_dim)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Did try using ChatGPT but the corrections offered also throws error.

What is the best way to replace this RNN with the Decision Transformer class declared above in the code?

Comment: Does `ensuring the output remains the same` refer to the values or just the shape of the output tensors?

Comment: both the values and the shape, since I would not like to break the remaining code integrity linked to the original RNN code

Comment: That won't work. The transformer is more powerful than the RNN (more parameters) and will therefore produce different values. Maybe over time, they will become similar, but producing identical values is highly unlikely.

Comment: if that is the case, then what do you suggest is the way to deal with the output shape? Since transformers do not maintain hidden states like RNN, how can this RNN be replaced with a transformer?